# streaming from LAN thumb drive with VPN running

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

In simplistic terms I’m tryin to see a thumb drive attached to my router from a fire stick that has a vpn running on the stick.  The router is 192.1.1. The stick is 192.168.1.54 in the router mapping list but when vpn is running the ip changes inside expressvpn to a 10... ip address so es file explorer can’t connect to the thumb drive neither can I stream media on the thumb drive through apps like Kodi, VLC Ext. When vpn is connected

Comment: Some VPN software connects you to a remote network, but then cuts off local network access (to protect the remote network from anything on your local network). See if there's anything in the settings to change this behaviour.